# Creating a function that takes the constructor of a generic class

Tags: typescript

##### The problem

I have the following setup ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGn6EALmIQJbAHwC2ApgMrFnAAKATvAA7QC80ArAG5c+YPAB2RVgFdgheKwAUADwBc0FAEosw-CPER4IGgDoQ8AObKNQ3QF9s97KEgwAQmFbQaSwjTEATGARkSVIxcwwcB2wY7AB6OPUAC1IYAHd5AGsYADMwmmwcqTFZUnFoYkyaCGDlNWCkMDEATzQtHF0E6GMe6Mrq2rEaNOh3RQAiFPGNa1j4xNcpQgqUmH94arEAckJC4tLy-prEAGF9QmlZeWVoNUJmjhp4HLhEdp1oLp7jPrAq4-gZwkFxkckUY1mXV00JheAAegiALTIlHQACCrHMUloYmWzwqDxo0B2hPxYy20FS0DE8GW81hDMZuhcpHMYjAACMjBV4NAOB4wLRfJ58fdHsSxU8XsEtj9Yl0ALJgZocokASQISXgUhA-mgVD+RMISSJRRKZHKYGg5j8NFY5AA-HtzWUxBVDQCTmCAOK2+3AVBeHx+QIEx744JoOrqd6dRLfX7-YJe+S+ob+hQQoRQpkwhFwlHI6mcAryxIoVbQDKsbIAGmgHKW0A1622yzSTWWcmgwEgyxoADc7c0KqRaM2e2AQCAVqb9haxD8jsnzpcwZmPNBIGGpa94LNYmaDm7+axBTRhRAAPJiEDNQPeXwBIKIRotNBR1TQBTfDzmCBqE0zRaNwGCaNocbdL09inuel43neG6sBo9K5tA+aFkWKCEhKpIvOSfLsAOpD+NUxb6iQwBJNAOTyLOqFoYyECsuyhBSKwRJbD+PR-gBW4tBo9SvkBaCynMXQVlS1Z1g2TY0iMGq9m2W7AMA1QwEQJDkIRJasGQ1RLjhQKSKCdG8LA86utAABkWA6XIkpCcgInQPYR4LtAUgQDQbC0rShIKFcrBqMZIJBbGegSIYJhmJYQXGAYtAMFpLDsBwsyQYx6H5jluUFph0C+Y8ekjlsiX0Iw5BFRS6zVB8OZZY1ug0v2SipHibqSsSoVrvIWzRF5PnsA5AVZtgQA)):

```
class Foo<T> {
    constructor(x: T) {
        console.log(x);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo<string> {

}
```

Now I want to create a function that takes any extended constructor of `Foo`.

Instances work fine:

```
function takesFoo(x: Foo<any>) {
    // ...
}
takesFoo(new Bar("hi"));
```

But if I want to take a constructor it fails:

```
function takesFooConstructor(x : typeof Foo) {
    // ...
}
takesFooConstructor(Bar);
//                  ^^^------ Argument of type 'typeof Bar' is not 
//                            assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Foo'.
```

Why does this not work and how can I fix this?

##### Some things I already tried

```
// Maybe I should make the function a generic?
function takesFooCtorGeneric<T extends typeof Foo>(x: T) {
    // ...
}
takesFooCtorGeneric(Bar);
//                  ^^^----- nope
```

```
// This works, but I don't want to cast every time I call the function.
takesFooConstructor(Bar as typeof Foo);
```

```
function parametersOnly<T extends Foo<any>>(x: (...args: any) => T) {
    // ...
}
parametersOnly(Bar)
//             ^^^------ Type 'typeof Bar' provides no match for the
//                       signature '(...args: any): Foo<any>'.
```

```
// This works, but now I can't access static properties.
type Constructor = Function & { prototype: Foo<any> }
function usePrototype(ctor: Constructor) {
    console.log(ctor.someStaticProp);
    //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------ Property 'someStaticProp' does
    //                                    not exist on type 'Constructor'
}
usePrototype(Bar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Constructors of classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) in TypeScript has following signature: `new` and call signature. In your case, constructor of `Bar` has type `new (x: string) => Bar`.

If you want `takesFooConstructor` take `Foo` constructor:

```
function takesFooAndExtendersOfFooConstructorWitoutDefinedT(x : new <T>(x: T) => Foo<T>)
```

But in that case `takesFooConstructor` cannot take Bar constructor, because you have already defined `T` type parameter of `Foo`.

If you want `takesFooConstructor` take `Foo` constructor and constructors of any class that extends `Foo`:

```
function takesAnyConstructorsOfFooAndExtendersOfFoo<T>(x : new (x: T) => Foo<T>)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGn6EALmIQJbAHwC2ApgMrFnAAKATvAA7QC80ArAG5c%20YPAB2RVgFdgheKwAUADwBc0FAEosw-CPER4IGgDoQ8AObKNQ3QF9s97KEgwAQmFbQaSwjTEATGARkSVIxcwwcB2wncChodwAvVAxvXwCgxBTtaJiAMykxWVJxaGIAaxoIAGF9QmlZeQB1UjkpQgARGjywmn8UZWg1MRoAd2gU5TVNHgxglK0o%20wqq2ol6mTlWFrbO7t7%20hWDraAB6U%20gAeQBpbBWauoatnfh2rp6Rw-dWE-OvVnYrAANNAAEY0YBgKQQGgJDzQfz7T7qaCQAj1MLmO5gSoPdZPZqtV57D59AZJX4XG75QrFUr3NaSTbyCCXPIAUR8fkRrFZeXm6EGwzG0Cm6i03DmWXQixiyxxq0ezN5bM56R5fOCCgpAjOVNuDKVjRVHK5ARoJq130pVwNCrxTONfLV3ItmsQR0QNpuQA) with both approaches

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! I still can't access static properties, but I guess I should just cast the parameter inside the function then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `Foo` is generic. This means `takesFooConstructor` would expect to receive a generic class it would work [Ex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGn6EALmIQJbAHwC2ApgMrFnAAKATvAA7QC80ArAG5c+YPAB2RVgFdgheKwAUADwBc0FAEosw-CPER4IGgDoQ8AObKNQ3QF9s97KEgwAQmFaoMNJYRpiAExgEZHRtB2xI7AB6aOhXKUJoQgALUhgA+BoIMQByQmwAMykxWVJxZLAAa2yQgGF9QmlZeS9laDVCAE8OGnhCuEQtHF1Y6GMJiOIaiHrG5rlFd1ZrbGnaxAaJJplFhRDVoA). This is because takesFooConstructor could instantiate the class passed in as a parameter with any `T`, but `Bar` only accepts `string`.

You can use a constructor signature instead, although you will have to rewrite the constructor arguments:

```
function takesFooConstructor<T>(x : new (x: T) => Foo<T>) {
    
}
takesFooConstructor(Bar);
takesFooConstructor(Foo);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGn6EALmIQJbAHwC2ApgMrFnAAKATvAA7QC80ArAG5c+YPAB2RVgFdgheKwAUADwBc0FAEosw-CPER4IGgDoQ8AObKNQ3QF9s97KEgwAQmFaoMNJYRpiAExgEZHRtB2xI7AB6aOhXKUJoQgALUhgA+BoIMQByQmwAMykxWVJxZLAAa2yQgGF9QmlZeS9laDVCAE8OGnhCuEQtHF1Y6GMJiOIaiHrG5rlFd1ZrbGnaxAaJJplFhRDVoA)